# C# Best pattern for actions triggered by dates

Tags: c#, email, timer

I've written applications to handle this situation dozens of times over the years. I just want to know if there's a better way.

**Here are some examples:**

A table contains an expiration date. After that date, I need to make a notification of the expiration (email, messenger, etc).

Someone has not logged in for X days. Need to send a notification.

**The way I currently handle it:**

1. Create a table of sent notifications.
2. Create a view in the database of all expirations/late logins with no record of a notification already sent.
3. Write a Windows Service to scan the view every X minutes and send the notifications, write them out to the "Sent Notifications" table (which will make it disappear from the view).

Is there any better way of accomplishing this task? I only ask because sometimes some new technology passes me by.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you could find a possible solution via SSIS (Sql Server Integration Services). You can create a package to monitor the porcess and to send email to those people who need to be informed.